# Characterization of Inner Automorphisms of a Von Neumann Algebra.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let M be a Von Neumann Algebra, an automorphism is said to be inner if it is of the form $Ad(u): x \to uxu^*$ for some unitary $ u \in M$ When M is a factor, show that

> $\alpha \in Aut(M)$ is inner iff $\exists 0 \neq y \in M$ such that $y \alpha(x)=xy$ for every $x \in M$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Um why the down vote on my question?

Comment: There is a group of people here, who most likely don't even know what a von Neumann algebra is, that expect you to "show your work".

Comment: @Martin, I have absolutely no idea who downvoted this or any other question, but such speculation here is quite pointless and out of place :-/

Comment: @Mariano, I don't think it is pointless. A user is met with unexplained downvotes. "Deal with it" is not a very nice attitude, in my opinion. And it is not the first time that people who have zero reputation in the areas related to a question like this vote to close, and I feel that reflects very poorly on our site.

Comment: Essentially all upvotes are also unexplained and no one complains about that.  On the other hand, it is simply impossible to know what experience the downvotes have in this or on any other subject, both when they downvote and when they upvotes. That is how the site works. And it is pointless to argue about this **here** You can of course search in meta for any of the several threads on the subject and revive it. But doing that **here** is not going to help with anything.

Comment: And the question is closed by 5 users who have a total of zero reputation in the tags involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $\alpha$ is inner. Then $\alpha=u\cdot u^*$ for some unitary $u$, and
$$
u^*\alpha(x)=xu^*
$$
for all $x\in M$.

Conversely, if there exists $y\in M$ such that $y\alpha(x)=xy$ for all $x\in M$, let $y=vr$ be the polar decomposition, with $r=(y^*y)^{1/2}$. We have
$$
y^*y\alpha(x)=y^*xy=(x^*y)^*y=(y\alpha(x^*))^*y=\alpha(x)y^*y.
$$
As this works for all $x\in M$ and $\alpha$ is an automorphism, we get that $y^*y\in\mathcal Z(M)=\mathbb C I$. It follows that $r\in\mathbb C I$ too. So now we have that
$$
v^*\alpha(x)=xv,\ \ \ x\in M.
$$
Using the same trick as before we find that $vv^*\in\mathbb C I$; as it is a projection and $y\ne 0$, we have $vv^*=I$. Then
$$
\alpha(x)=vxv^*,\ \ \ x\in M.
$$
Also,
$$
\alpha(v^*v)=vv^*vv^*=vv^*=I.
$$
As $\alpha$ is an automorphism, $v^*v=I$ and so $v$ is a unitary.